# How to use multiple query strings with aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to use multiple query strings with aggregate functions in elasticsearch?
For example:

```
if a>0 AND a<1, then {"low":count(aggregate count of records within 0 to 1)}
else if a > 1 AND a < 100, then {"normal":count(aggregate count of records within 1 to 100)}
else {"high":count(aggregate count of records after 100)}
```

How to achieve this using Request Body Query string?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `a` here? Some field you search on? The number of documents in the search result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` is a field that you search on, I think the easiest way for you to do that is using the [range aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) with buckets for each of your use-cases (low, normal, high).

You cannot bind aggregations to conditions of your query. That you would have to do in code yourself. But if you use the range aggregation, you could define your buckets like

```
POST /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "a_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "a",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "to" : 1 },
                    { "from" : 1, "to" : 10 },
                    { "from" : 10 }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your query, two of these buckets would remain empty, but this should give you the result you want